# How do you operate the elevator in Stellar Bay?

Tags: the-outer-worlds

The controls for the elevator are too far from the elevator platform. When going down, you need to trigger the elevator and then jump on it as it's going down. When going up, if you trigger the elevator and then attempt to get on it, you get minced in the machinery.

How do you use the landing pad elevator in Stellar Bay?

(Yes, I know that I can fast-travel to the interior of the Unreliable; sometimes you just wanna walk...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most elevators in the game have a call button/switch on either end (just in case the elevator is in the wrong position) plus a control on the elevator. The Stellar Bay landing pad is no exception. Although this one is easy to miss, particularly when coming at the elevator from the town side, as the controls are on the side and not directly in front of you.

When looking at the elevator from the up on the landing pad side, the controls are on the left hand side, next to the ledge with no railing (pictured below).

[image: Stellar Bay landing pad elevator switch]

Comment: Oh, OK. I was so fixated on the "call" controls that I completely missed the one on the elevator itself.

Comment: I missed it at first too. I just jumped down.